# How can i get only spesific results with xmlpullparser

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

I want to list some items at listview from xml daily.For this I created `<date>27.11.2015</date>` tags in my items and i am using xmlpullparser.But it shows all items at list normally.How can I get only current date's items?

**XML**

```
<resources>
<food>
    <date>28.10.2015</date>
    <img>http://.....png</img>
    <name>taze fasülye</name>
    <calories>488 Kalori</calories>
</food>

<food>
    <date>28.11.2015</date>
    <img>http....png</img>
    <name>bamya</name>
    <calories>110 Kalori</calories>
</food>

<food>
    <date>29.11.2015</date>
    <img>http://...png</img>
    <name>kıyma</name>
    <calories>682 Kalori</calories>


</food>
```

**PullParser.java**

```
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

            String tagname = xpp.getName();


            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("food")) {

                        curFood = new FoodItem();
                    }
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:

                    curText = xpp.getText();
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("food")) {

                        foods.add(curFood);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {

                        curFood.setName(curText);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("date")) {

                        curFood.setDate(curText);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("img")) {

                        curFood.setImgUrl(curText);
                    }
                    else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("calories")) {

                        curFood.setCalories(curText);
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            eventType = xpp.next();
```

I wish it showed only today's food.Is it possible? [Also I created currentDate same as type of my date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg7Nq.png)

Comment: you have to first check the date means there will be one condition which will check the date and if its today date then it will check for further key otherwise it will not.

Comment: Code headings should be neatly formatted and while naming a java class naming conventions should follow